# how to disable update and delete on a MongoDB collection?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I want to disable update and delete queries on a collection. first I wanted to use triggers but MongoDB on our server doesn't support triggers(only MongoDB atlas does that). then I wanted to revoke update and delete permission from my user role, that I didn't find a way to do that. is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom role for this task as follow:

```
db.createRole(
{
 role: "foobarRole",
 privileges: [
   { resource: { db: "exampleDb", collection: "bar" }, actions: [  "find", "insert" ] }
 ],
   roles: []
 }
)
```

And grant the role to the user:

```
db.grantRolesToUser(
 "foobarUser",
 [
  { role: "foobarRole", db: "exampleDb" }
 ]
)
```

Comment: I want my user to have all dbAdmin accesses but update and delete for a collection

Comment: you can add explicitly any actions you need excluding the ones that you dont need ...

Comment: is there any way to inherit all of a role's privileges and exclude some?

Comment: You can see what roles and privileges you inherit with the rolesinfo command: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/rolesInfo/#mongodb-data-rolesInfo.inheritedPrivileges   , and you can grant or revoke any role you want ...